# How to enable and disable button using summernote?

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

Is it possible to disable/enable the buttons of the editor **without removing the buttons from the toolbar?**

Summernote toolbar looks like this:

```
toolbar: [
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['color', ['color']]
  ]
```

I want to disable the "color" button while at the same time **keeping it visible on the toolbar**

Im using Summernote library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Simply inspect the element to get the id/class for the button you want to disable and use jquery/javascript to disable it.

```
$('.btn-codeview').prop('disabled', true);
```

OR

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-codeview")[0].disabled = true;
```